# multilevel regression model for nested data?

Tags: r, regression, anova, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

**Hypothesis 1**
Independent variable = Thermal inertia (TI)
Dependent variable = Depth diameter ratio (d/D), Radii variation (RV) and Rim irregularity (RI).

**Hypothesis 2**
**Independent variable** = Thermal inertia (TI)
**Dependent variable** = Mantled Rim percentage (MRI)

For testing hypothesis 1, I have to test correlation of d/D, RV and RI with thermal inertia.
For 2nd hypothesis Correlation of MRP with thermal inertia.
Total craters = 138 (ID), Scenes (group) = 18. Repeated measurements were taken for each crater. Craters are nested within scenes, TI values are nested within scenes, and collected data (d/D, RV, RI, MRP) nested within scenes.
I have to compare TI both within and between scenes, also the statistical significance of each model result determined using a likelihood ratio test to attain p-values. Since I am new to R and statistics, if anyone could help me in understanding the design it will be of great help to me.
I have to look for p-values and results supporting hypothesis1 or 2?

[image: Data]